# How can I extend a class from a gem with a method?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Trying to extend the (terrific) ([mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail)), and having trouble with that.

Mail can be used like so:

- Mail.all
- Mail.first
- Mail.delete_all()

And I would like to extend that, with: move_all()
I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/network/retriever_methods/imap.rb)  and seems like the right place to exentend the IMAP < Retriever class, so it sits right besides; delete_all(). The code is almost the same as well.

But I'm doing something wrong, I can get it to work, here is the consise version, I would like to get working:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'net/imap'
require 'mail' #https://github.com/mikel/mail

module Mail
    class IMAP < Retriever
    require 'net/imap' unless defined?(Net::IMAP)
    
    
        # Move all emails from an IMAP mailbox to another IMAP mailbox within the same account
        def move_all(mailbox='INBOX', target='')
            puts "How dow we get this to show?"
        end

    end
end

Mail.defaults do
    retriever_method :imap, :address    => MAIL_SERVER,
                            :port       => 993,
                            :user_name  => USERNAME,
                            :password   => PASSWORD,
                            :enable_ssl => true
                                                    
end

# WHY doesn't this work:
#
Mail.move_all('INBOX', 'another_box')
#   ^^^^^^^^^
#   gives error:  undefined method `move_all' for Mail:Module (NoMethodError)


# and does this works: 
Mail.delete_all()
```

Like you can see: Mail.delete_all() works just fine, but the extended method 'move_all()' on the IMAP < Retriever class doesn't get recognized.

What I did try:

- remove the '< Retriever'
- called the methode in other ways:
- Mail.Retriever.IMAP.move_all
- Mail::Retriever.IMAP.move_all
- etc all kind of variations. But that's out of desperation.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

Thank you for the time and effort
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `Mail.delete_all()` is defined here https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/10a4443b9d4ffa71b9ad643ad86cc23ccc99f0f3/lib/mail/mail.rb#L174.
You need to create class method `move_all` in the `Mail` module.

```rb
  def self.move_all(*args, &block)
    retriever_method.move_all(*args, &block)
  end
```

Comment: Aaah! That's what I was missing, the place where ```Mail.delete_all()``` it gets defined. Great, thank you so much, learn a lot from this 'bug'. Cheers